# Find some $n, k$ such that: $\phi(kn) = k * \phi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

This question might be a duplicate.

> For what positive integers $n$, $k$ is $\phi(kn) = k \cdot \phi(n)$?

I read [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function) but I did not find any identity to help me answer the question so I tried some examples that given identity works:

$$k = 1, n = 1\\
k = 2, n = 2\\
k = 3, n = 3\\
k = 4, n = 4\\
k = 5, n = 5\\
k = 6, n = 6\\
k = 7, n = 7\\
k = 9, n = 9\\
k = 10, n = 10$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @fleablood $\phi$ is multiplicative but not completely multiplicative: $\phi(kn) = \phi(k) \phi(n)$ if $k$ and $n$ are coprime, but generally not otherwise.

Comment: Consider phi ($\prod p_i^{n_i})=\prod p_i (p^{n-1}-1) $  find when $\prod etc= phi (nk)=n\prod etc $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is that every prime dividing $k$ divides $n$.
To see this, let $k = k_1 k_2$ and $n = n_1 n_2$ where $k_1$ and $n_1$ are divisible by the same set $S$ of primes, while $k_2$ and $n_2$ are coprime to each other and to $k_1$ and $n_1$.  Thus we have
$$ \frac{\varphi(k n)}{k \varphi(n)} = \frac{\varphi(k_1 n_1) \varphi(k_2) \varphi(n_2)}{k_1 k_2 \varphi(n_1) \varphi(n_2)} = \frac{\varphi(k_1 n_1) \varphi(k_2) }{k_1 k_2 \varphi(n_1) } $$
But if $k_1 = \prod_{p \in S} p^{d(p)}$ and $n_1 = \prod_{p \in S} p^{e(p)}$, where $d(p) \ge 1$ and $e(p) \ge 1$, we have
$$ \frac{\varphi(k_1 n_1)}{k_1 \varphi(n_1)} = \prod_{p \in S} \frac{(p-1) p^{e(p)+d(p)-1}}{p^{d(p)}(p-1)p^{e(p)-1}} = 1$$
So the condition reduces to 
$ \varphi(k_2) = k_2$, and this is only true for $k_2 = 1$.